# How to ensure resources show up in chef server run log details

Tags: chef-infra

I have a cookbook that uses custom LWRPs; in the actions of these LWRPs, they call other resources (file, directory, execute, etc). The inner resources do not show up in the run history 'Details' section on chef server, but they do show up in the INFO log during provisioning on the node. How can I ensure that they show up in the Details section as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested resources are explicitly suppressed from the reporting data: https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/master/lib/chef/resource_reporter.rb#L312-L315

You would have to build your own system for this.